# How to use the monitor traffic only shows the In packages in Juniper EX480?

Tags: juniper

I use `monitor traffic` tool:

`run monitor traffic interface ae16` commad:

```
19:04:52.820205 Out arp who-has 16.23.40.133 tell 16.23.40.134              
19:04:52.820210 Out arp who-has 43.243.33.66 tell 43.243.33.70                  
19:04:52.820216 Out arp who-has 16.23.40.45 tell 16.23.40.46                
19:04:52.820243 Out arp who-has 16.23.40.242 tell 16.23.40.246              
19:04:52.820250 Out arp who-has 16.23.43.199 tell 16.23.43.222              
19:04:52.820256 Out arp who-has 43.243.33.204 tell 43.243.33.206                
19:04:52.820261 Out arp who-has 16.23.43.121 tell 16.23.43.126              
19:04:52.820266 Out arp who-has 16.23.42.27 tell 16.23.42.254               
19:04:52.820270 Out arp who-has 16.23.42.18 tell 16.23.42.254               
19:04:52.820276 Out arp who-has 16.23.40.245 tell 16.23.40.246              
19:04:52.820281 Out arp who-has 16.23.42.220 tell 16.23.42.254              
19:04:52.820301 Out arp who-has 16.23.40.60 tell 16.23.40.62                
19:04:52.820307 Out arp who-has 16.23.41.209 tell 16.23.41.214              
19:04:52.820312 Out arp who-has 16.23.42.217 tell 16.23.42.254              
19:04:52.822060 Out arp who-has 16.23.41.181 tell 16.23.41.182              
19:04:52.854163 Out arp who-has 16.23.41.129 tell 16.23.41.134
....
```

there have many `Out` packages, I want to only shows the `In` direction packages, how   I use `monitor traffic` tool:

`run monitor traffic interface ae16` commad:

```
19:04:52.820205 Out arp who-has 16.23.40.133 tell 16.23.40.134              
19:04:52.820210 Out arp who-has 43.243.33.66 tell 43.243.33.70                  
19:04:52.820216 Out arp who-has 16.23.40.45 tell 16.23.40.46                
19:04:52.820243 Out arp who-has 16.23.40.242 tell 16.23.40.246              
19:04:52.820250 Out arp who-has 16.23.43.199 tell 16.23.43.222              
19:04:52.820256 Out arp who-has 43.243.33.204 tell 43.243.33.206                
19:04:52.820261 Out arp who-has 16.23.43.121 tell 16.23.43.126              
19:04:52.820266 Out arp who-has 16.23.42.27 tell 16.23.42.254               
19:04:52.820270 Out arp who-has 16.23.42.18 tell 16.23.42.254               
19:04:52.820276 Out arp who-has 16.23.40.245 tell 16.23.40.246              
19:04:52.820281 Out arp who-has 16.23.42.220 tell 16.23.42.254              
19:04:52.820301 Out arp who-has 16.23.40.60 tell 16.23.40.62                
19:04:52.820307 Out arp who-has 16.23.41.209 tell 16.23.41.214              
19:04:52.820312 Out arp who-has 16.23.42.217 tell 16.23.42.254              
19:04:52.822060 Out arp who-has 16.23.41.181 tell 16.23.41.182              
19:04:52.854163 Out arp who-has 16.23.41.129 tell 16.23.41.134
....
```

There have many `Out` packages, I want to only shows the `In` direction packages, how to use the monitor traffic?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juniper's `monitor traffic` command has the same functionality as `tcpdump`, and as such you can build custom filters to suit what you want to see.

Below you can see inbound and outbound traffic for IP, IPv6, and ISO/CLNS (IS-IS).

```
jhead@vmx1# run monitor traffic interface ge-0/0/0 no-resolve
verbose output suppressed, use <detail> or <extensive> for full protocol decode
Address resolution is OFF.
Listening on ge-0/0/0, capture size 96 bytes

06:14:40.613070  In IS-IS, p2p IIH, src-id 0168.0000.0003, length 57
06:14:40.633073  In IP 192.168.0.3.49152 > 192.168.0.1.4784: BFDv1, Multi-hop Control, State Up, Flags: [Authentication Present], length: 44
06:14:40.901500 Out IS-IS, p2p IIH, src-id 0168.0000.0001, length 57
06:14:41.282872  In IP6 2001:db8:3000::3.49152 > 2001:db8:3000::1.4784: [|BFD]
06:14:41.462494  In IS-IS, p2p IIH, src-id 0168.0000.0003, length 57
06:14:41.841509 Out IS-IS, p2p IIH, src-id 0168.0000.0001, length 57
06:14:41.881561 Out IP6 truncated-ip6 - 32 bytes missing!2001:db8:3000::1.49152 > 2001:db8:3000::3.4784: [|BFD]
```

To see just inbound, use the `matching` keyword, which allows you to build filters that you would use in `tcpdump` or wireshark.  In this case, that's the `inbound` filter, we will also only match on IP traffic.

```
jhead@vmx1# run monitor traffic interface ge-0/0/0 no-resolve matching "inbound && ip"
verbose output suppressed, use <detail> or <extensive> for full protocol decode
Address resolution is OFF.
Listening on ge-0/0/0, capture size 96 bytes

06:17:01.931758  In IP 192.168.0.3.49152 > 192.168.0.1.4784: BFDv1, Multi-hop Control, State Up, Flags: [Authentication Present], length: 44
06:17:02.202380  In IP 192.168.0.3.55330 > 192.168.0.1.179: . ack 3564494504 win 16384 <nop,nop,timestamp 25559251 25558745>
06:17:03.711791  In IP 192.168.0.3.49152 > 192.168.0.1.4784: BFDv1, Multi-hop Control, State Up, Flags: [Authentication Present], length: 44
06:17:05.431838  In IP 192.168.0.3.49152 > 192.168.0.1.4784: BFDv1, Multi-hop Control, State Up, Flags: [Authentication Present], length: 44
```

Comment: Is it possible to filter a special IP address?